# Vue.js Watcher on a storeState data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In my Vue.js I have a function that get labels from a picture using Google Vision. This function is inside a `mixin` so my code is not so bloated.

I then store the labels as an array in a `storeState` so I can access it in other components.

What I want is to call another function as soon as my array is stored. So I implemented a watcher:

```
watch: {
    this.storeState.labels: function () {
      anotheFunction()
      } 
    }
```

But I get a  `Unexpected keyword 'this'` error. So how can I trigger another function as soon as my `this.storeState.labels` is updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watch that property without using  `this` keyword :

```
watch: {
    "storeState.labels": function () {
      anotheFunction()
      } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You ahve to create a computed property first, and then watch that computed property to perform your operations upon changing

```
computed:{
    labels(){
       return this.storeState.labels; // did you mean return this.$store.state.labels ?
    }
},

watch:{
    labels:{
       handler:function(){
                anotherFunction()     
               }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 way to do that. First using quotes syntax.

```
watch: {
  'storeState.labels'() {
     // Do your magic here..
  }
}
```

and second way is that watch the object deeply.

```
watch: {
  storeState: {
     deep: true,
     handler() {
       // Do your magic here
       // This way watches all your object changes so then while using this be sure that you're doing right magic
     }
  }
}
```

In addition, both case you should have a computed value to use `storeState` object in Vue side.